# Creating disk image where destination partition is smaller than the source

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, disk-image

It seems one of the requirements of a disk image tool like Clonezilla is that the destination partition for the image is at least as large as the source partition.

I have a Windows disk that I would like to create a backup image file from. It's on a 1TB drive, but only ~120G of that space is being used. At the moment, I only have a spare 500G drive onto which to place the image file. I cannot modify the source partition.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Macrium Reflect from the Windows side.  I used that to put a 160G Windows installation onto a 60G SSD, so the smaller target is possible.  Copy both the EFI partition (if a UEFI machine) and the Windows partition if you want to make a bootable target.

Comment: Thanks! I was sort of hoping to do this from Ubuntu, hence the reason I'm here... ; ) But if it isn't possible (or at least not easily possible) then I guess that's the way to go.